How do I keep track of a bone across armature .join()s? (Or, is there a better way to write this armature-merging script?)
The premise: I have a script to merge multiple selected armatures into the active armature, based on the following requirements:

If two bones of the same name have the same local position and rotation (within a tolerance), the bones are "merged": the bone in the active armature is kept, and the others are deleted. Any parenting of the deleted bones should be transferred to the "merged" bone.
Otherwise - the incoming bone is not within tolerance of the active bone, or the active armature doesn't have a bone of that name - the active armature keeps the incoming bone, unaltered.
Comparing bones should be done in local space, but any "unmerged" bones should keep their position in world space.
Any children of the merged armatures should end up fully attached to the active one.

Example "before":

Example "after":

Bones 1 and 2 were "merged". Bone 3 was not. Bones 4 and Q are both present and unchanged.
(Based on this example, the world space requirement may seem strange, but it is indeed necessary. In most situations, the armatures will be in the same place anyway, so it won't look weird like this.)
The current script: (simplified a bit to remove irrelevant stuff)
def merge_selected_to_active_armatures(self, context, force=False):
    # assume all selected objects are armatures and there's more than one of them
    targetObject = context.view_layer.objects.active
    selectedObjects = context.view_layer.objects.selected

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    targetBones = targetObject.data.edit_bones
    targetNameList = [b.name for b in targetBones]
    for otherObject in selectedObjects:
        if targetObject == otherObject: continue
        # move all the armature's children right now to get it out of the way
        for c in otherObject.children:
            c.parent = targetObject
            for m in c.modifiers:
                if m.type == "ARMATURE" and m.object == otherObject:
                    m.object = targetObject
        otherBones = otherObject.data.edit_bones
        keep = []
        toss = []
        for otherBone in otherBones:
            if otherBone.name not in targetNameList:
                keep.append(otherBone)
                continue
            targetBone = targetBones[otherBone.name]
            areTheSame = isBonePairIdentical(targetBone,otherBone) # the position & rotation compare
            if areTheSame or force:
                toss.append(otherBone)
            else:
                keep.append(otherBone)
        for schmuck in toss:
            otherBones.remove(schmuck)

    # at this point, we have removed all the stuff we don't want to keep, so join the rest
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
    bpy.ops.object.join()
    return {"FINISHED"}

The problem: As-is, this script loses all bone parenting that's not in the active armature.
I tried a few things, but I can't find a way out of the Catch-22:

We can't re-parent anything until after the .join(), because parenting bones across different armatures (sensibly) doesn't work. So we must wait until after the .join() to re-parent.
As soon as the .join() runs, all established information about the current bones is either lost or worthless. Any references to the actual bones are still trapped in the old armature data block. Any references to the bones' names are invalid because we have no idea how the join may have resolved collisions. Furthermore, while the .join() very helpfully does the worldspace requirement automatically, we can no longer compare bones after it because two bones the same in local space no longer are. So we cannot wait until after the .join() to figure out which bones to merge, and thus figure out what re-parenting needs to be done.

So the question: How do I keep track of bones before and after the .join()?
Alternatively, I am open to getting around the problem by writing the script in a different way.

Custom properties on the bones appear to be preserved across joins.

scurest mentioned custom properties (something I haven't really looked at before) and that's exactly what I needed.
The solution: if a bone is to be deleted as merged, assign to it the target bone's name as a custom property. After the .join(), this can be read and used to get the parenting right. Since the target bone is of the acive armature, we know it will not be renamed after the .join().
New code:
def merge_selected_to_active_armatures(self, context, force=False):
    # assume all selected objects are armatures and there's more than one of them
    targetObject = context.view_layer.objects.active
    selectedObjects = context.view_layer.objects.selected

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    targetBones = targetObject.data.edit_bones
    targetNameList = [b.name for b in targetBones]
    for otherObject in selectedObjects:
        if targetObject == otherObject: continue
        # move all the armature's children right now to get it out of the way
        for c in otherObject.children:
            c.parent = targetObject
            for m in c.modifiers:
                if m.type == "ARMATURE" and m.object == otherObject:
                    m.object = targetObject
        otherBones = otherObject.data.edit_bones
        for otherBone in otherBones:
            if otherBone.name not in targetNameList:
                continue
            targetBone = targetBones[otherBone.name]
            areTheSame = isBonePairIdentical(targetBone,otherBone) # the position & rotation compare
            if areTheSame or force:
                otherBone["mergeInto"] = targetBone.name
            else:
                pass # the actual code will notify the user about this later

    # decisions made, do the join
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
    bpy.ops.object.join()

    # go back for every bone on which we assigned "mergeInto" and actually do said merge
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
    joinedBones = targetObject.data.edit_bones
    for bone in [j for j in joinedBones if "mergeInto" in j]:
        targetBone = joinedBones[bone["mergeInto"]]
        bone.parent = targetBone # so the deletion will automatically pass along parenting
        joinedBones.remove(bone)

    # done
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
    return {"FINISHED"}

